# Choosing lifetime for stateless services

Tags: dependency-injection, lifetime

Some service types have pretty clear lifetime requirements. For example, if one is using EntityFramework in an ASP.NET app, it is clear that the `DbContext` lifetime should be tied to the request. However, there are some services that are "stateless": they do not store any state, and instead just forward instructions to their dependencies. A simple case would be a `Query` object:

```cs
public class MyQuery : IQuery<SomeQuery, SomeResponse> {
    private readonly IRepository<MyTable> Repository; // Injected via constructor
    public SomeResponse Query(SomeQuery query) {
        return Repository.All().Where(r => r.Field == query.Field)
               .Select(r => new SomeResponse { Field = r.Field }).Single();
    }
}
```

This particular class has no requirements itself, other than those imposed by its dependencies. What guidelines should be used to determine the lifetime to choose for this type of object? Should one use a transient lifetime whenever possible? Or should one have the longest lifetime possible? And why?